# how to use at command to schedule browser opening at a scheduled time

Tags: command-line

how   to open Mozilla browser home page in 2 mins of current time using the at command on command line?

Comment: `sleep 120; firefox;` ?

Comment: There is `at` command which is for scheduling and remembers scheduling even after reboot. i recommend that

Answer (score 0):

`sleep 120; firefox;` Is correct.

But to clarify:

- sleep is counted in seconds so `sleep 120` is what you need for it to wait 2 minutes.
- Then `firefox` is what you need to open a browser.

If you'd like it to open say Google, the command is

`firefox https://google.com`